# Api is not fetching in reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to fetch food by its key. In postman api is working fine but is the forntend it has no response.
backend code

```
 app.get('/foods/:key', (req, res) => {
    foodsCollection.find({ key: req.params.key }).toArray((err, documents) => {
      res.send(documents[0])
    })
  })
```

frontend code

```
const { key } = useParams()
  const [foodById, setFoodById] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/foods/${key}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setFoodById(data)
      })
  }, [key])
```

[image: This is the frontend page]

[image: Route page]

[image: Api is working]

[image: Not rendering in the frontend]

Comment: I think you're facing CORS problem, see this https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: We need more precisions, what is not working ? 'res' has results ?

Comment: You should check the server is running on port **5000**, what does the **Network** tab of your browser's Developer Tools state? 4XX error. Can you make the request via `curl`? e.g. `curl http://localhost:5000/foods/key`, replacing `key` with a real value

Comment: Show the error occurred, causes in the developer tools.

Comment: res has no result. It is not even responding in and nothing is showing in console log.

Comment: now its showing in the console ```data1 SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at FoodMenu.js:51```

Comment: What status of '/foods/:key' request return in your developer tool ?

Comment: Please add more context to your question for e.g. the screenshot of the network tab which shows the request headers, response status, etc. You may hide the API endpoint if it's not public. Either the API has CORS issue or its Server to Server API.

Comment: "data1 SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at FoodMenu.js:51" sounds like you're expecting `JSON` but the response is not `JSON`. Make sure you're doing `res.json(...)` and `documents[0]` is actually something that can be stringified, e.g. an object. Also, if it works in `Postman` but doesn't in your client-side code, it's most likely a `CORS` issue.

Comment: Can you console log the key that you are passing to the URL. inside the useeffect. Before the fetch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you've added some images above, the most important is missing, namely, what are the Browser's **Developer Tools** stating the problem is. You should see some message in the `Console` tab, as well as in the `Network` tab for that particular request, if it is indeed being made. Until anyone sees this, it will be very difficult to help in fixing your problem.

If your not already, I suggest scaffolding any react app with [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev) (CRA). This will give you a working app to start from. You can ignore **CORS** related issues in development, if using CRA, by adding `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"`, to your `package.json` file, see [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) for more on this method, but remember, this is only works for local development. You can also start **Chrome** to ignore **Web Security** by running it with the `--disable-web-security` flag e.g. `chromium --disable-web-security`, but that isn't a great idea really, more a way to quickly determine if you are having CORS problems, as Chrome masks some problems as CORS related, when in fact they aren't.

I'd also suggest changing your fetch code to use `await`, so instead you'd have:

```
const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/foods/${key}`);

if (!response.ok) {
  console.error(`Error message: ${response.statusText} ${response.status}`);
}

const result = response.json();
console.log(result);
```

This isn't necessary, but I've always found it way easier to read than the `then/catch/finally` method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you haven't set the [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) headers of response in your backend code. and you are using different ports in your backend and frontend (5000 & 3000) so the  Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource, indicating that the request was blocked due to violating the CORS security rules.

you've to set the CORS headers.

you can install the [CORS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) npm package and follow it's instructions to resolve the issue like this:

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()
 
app.use(cors())
.
.
.
```

And one other issue that I'm seeing is that you've put the react-router default route before your specified path. so move the `<route path="*">` after `<route path="/foods/:key">`

Comment: I think the problem is in the backend because the console.log of the backend is coming undefined. Can you give a soloution?

Comment: surely it's nothing wrong with the backend because you're getting your response when sending the request using  postman. Am I right? Can you console.log(req.params.key) in your backend code plz?

Comment: I am getting the value which I need in (req,params.key) .

Comment: are you using `mongodb drive' or 'mongoose'?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226713/discussion-between-md-irtiza-hossain-and-abbas).

Answer (score 0):

#### Reason for error

You need to **stringify** an object before sending it to the client with the `JSON.stringify()` method. When we exchange data to/from a web server, it must be a string.

#### Solution:

Proper way to send response to the client would to wrap the entire API in a `try-catch` block and explicitly specify the [HTTP Status Code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) along with the stringified data in every response.

**Note:** Although `500` status code is used for error handling, you should choose one as per the use case.

```
app.get('/foods/:key', (req, res) => {
  try {
    /*
      rest of the code
    */

    foodsCollection.find({ key: req.params.key }).toArray((err, documents) => {
      if (err) {
        // 500 stands for internal server error
        return res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify('Here goes a meaningful error message!'));
      }

      // 200 stands for success
      res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(documents[0]));
    });

    /*
      rest of the code
    */
  } catch (error) {
    // 500 stands for internal server error
    res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify('Here goes another meaningful error message!'));
  }
})
```

Comment: Okay will look into this further, could you please check my comment on your question?

Comment: Yes i am editing my post and giving more informantion.

Comment: Please check my comment. You've still not attached screenshot of Network.Tab

Comment: I have sorted it. It was a state problem in the frontend. Thank you all of you for giving such responses in a very short time.

Comment: Great! Please close the question so that others don’t invest their time in finding a solution :)